# Vertex Buffer Creating a Sqaure

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11, vertex-buffer

I'm trying to create a square using this tutorial here, http://www.braynzarsoft.net/index.php?p=D3D11BD:

However I'm having trouble creating the second triangle... see below

```
bool InitScene()
{
    //Compile Shaders from shader file
    hr = D3DX11CompileFromFile(L"Effects.fx", 0, 0, "VS", "vs_5_0", 0, 0, 0, &VS_Buffer, 0, 0);
    hr = D3DX11CompileFromFile(L"Effects.fx", 0, 0, "PS", "ps_5_0", 0, 0, 0, &PS_Buffer, 0, 0);

    //Create the Shader Objects
    hr = d3d11Device->CreateVertexShader(VS_Buffer->GetBufferPointer(), VS_Buffer->GetBufferSize(), NULL, &VS);
    hr = d3d11Device->CreatePixelShader(PS_Buffer->GetBufferPointer(), PS_Buffer->GetBufferSize(), NULL, &PS);

    //Set Vertex and Pixel Shaders
    d3d11DevCon->VSSetShader(VS, 0, 0);
    d3d11DevCon->PSSetShader(PS, 0, 0);

    //Create the vertex buffer
    Vertex v[] =
    {
        Vertex( -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f ),
        Vertex( -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f ),
        Vertex( 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f ),

        Vertex( -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f ),
        Vertex( 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f ),
        Vertex( 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f ),
    };

    D3D11_BUFFER_DESC vertexBufferDesc;
    ZeroMemory( &vertexBufferDesc, sizeof(vertexBufferDesc) );

    vertexBufferDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    vertexBufferDesc.ByteWidth = sizeof( Vertex ) * 6;
    vertexBufferDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
    vertexBufferDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    vertexBufferDesc.MiscFlags = 0;

    D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA vertexBufferData; 

    ZeroMemory( &vertexBufferData, sizeof(vertexBufferData) );
    vertexBufferData.pSysMem = v;
    hr = d3d11Device->CreateBuffer( &vertexBufferDesc, &vertexBufferData, &triangleVertBuffer);

    //Set the vertex buffer
    UINT stride = sizeof( Vertex );
    UINT offset = 0;
    d3d11DevCon->IASetVertexBuffers( 0, 1, &triangleVertBuffer, &stride, &offset );

    //Create the Input Layout
    d3d11Device->CreateInputLayout( layout, numElements, VS_Buffer->GetBufferPointer(), 
        VS_Buffer->GetBufferSize(), &vertLayout );

    //Set the Input Layout
    d3d11DevCon->IASetInputLayout( vertLayout );

    //Set Primitive Topology
    d3d11DevCon->IASetPrimitiveTopology( D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST );

    //Create the Viewport
    D3D11_VIEWPORT viewport;
    ZeroMemory(&viewport, sizeof(D3D11_VIEWPORT));

    viewport.TopLeftX = 0;
    viewport.TopLeftY = 0;
    viewport.Width = Width;
    viewport.Height = Height;

    //Set the Viewport
    d3d11DevCon->RSSetViewports(1, &viewport);

    return true;
}
```

Ive added another three vertices but the second triangle does not show.

Any idea would be grateful :)

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you set this to the number of points vertex points you have found in the DrawScene method:

```
//Draw the triangle
d3d11DevCon->Draw( 6, 0 );
```